# React: Yup conditional validation only when a field is visible

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to implement form validation using formik & yup in React. I have a login/register form with three fields (name,email,password). Name field is conditionally rendered when 'create an account' button is clicked. I want the name field to be required only when form is in **register** state. I'm using a state variable **isLogin** to save the form's current state, also using it to initialise **showName** boolean in formik's initialValues. Right now, name field has no validation applied on it and form can be submitted if **name** field is empty.

My Code

```
const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);

const initialAuthFormValues = {
  hideName: isLogin, 
  name: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
};
```

My Validation Schema

```
const authFormValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  hideName: Yup.boolean(),

  name: Yup.string().when("hideName",{
  is: false,
  then: Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
  }),

 email: Yup.string().required("Email is required"),
 password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
});
```

My Component looks like this

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialAuthFormValues}
  validationSchema={authFormValidationSchema}
  onSubmit={submitHandler}
>
  {(formik) => (
      <Form>
        {!isLogin && (
          <TextField
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder="Name"
          />
        )}
        <TextField
          label="Email"
          type="text"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
        />
        <TextField
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          
          <Button type="submit"> {isLogin ? "Login" : "Create Account"} </Button>
          
          <Button
            type="reset"
            className="toggle"
            onClick={() => { setIsLogin((prevState) => !prevState); }}
          >
            {isLogin ? "Create new account" : "Login with existing account"}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </section>
  )}
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to the problem : In my code, action is my prop

1. First, **create a variable in your JS** that will hold the logic:

```
let passwordTest
      
if (action === "Register") {
  passwordTest = {
    password2: Yup
      .string().trim()
      .required("Please confirm your password")
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match')
} else {
   passwordTest = null
}
```

> Basically above you are saying that if the props is Register (if this
> form is rendered for registering purpose and not login), then create
> the field apply the validation listed, otherwise, this field will be
> null.

2. Then, **in your Yup schema** destructure your variable :

```
const validationSchemaYup = Yup.object().shape({

other fields validation logic...
...passwordTest,
other fields validation logic...
```

> Here you add your new custom validation logic, don't forget to destructure!

Answer (score 0):

You can use authFormValidationSchema as a **state** , and **update** this state in case that button clicked :

```
const authFormValidationSchema = {
 email: Yup.string().required("Email is required"),
 password: Yup.string().required("Password is required"),
};
const [authFormValidationSchema, setAuthFormValidationSchema] = useState(Yup.object());
```

track the status when button is clicked in a useEffect, and update state of authFormValues accordingly :

```
useEffect(()=>{
  let authFormValidationSchema_ = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(authFormValidationSchema))
  if(!buttonIsClicked)
  setAuthFormValidationSchema(Yup.object(authFormValidationSchema_));
  else  setAuthFormValidationSchema(Yup.object({...authFormValidationSchema_, name: Yup.string().required("Name is required") }));
  },[buttonIsClicked]);
```